# Determine dependencies, might be cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following problem,

Determine how $x_1(\alpha)$ depends on $\alpha$ when $x_1(\alpha)$ is the first component of the solution
of the system $Ax = b$, where

A = $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1\\1 & -1 & 4\\1 & 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}$ and B = $\begin{bmatrix}-2\\\alpha\\1\end{bmatrix}$

I'm think Cramer's rule but am not sure what that would prove.

Answer (score 1):

Just using Cramer's rule directly, we get
\begin{align}
x_1(\alpha)=\frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{-2}&1&1\\\color{blue}{\alpha}&-1&4\\\color{blue}{1}&1&-2
\end{pmatrix}}{\det A}=\frac{3\alpha+9}{12}=\frac{\alpha+3}{4}.
\end{align}